# Sequence of Pointwise bounded bounded and equicontinous functions is uniformally bounded

Tags: real-analysis

The problem i have today is that let K be a compact space and fn   be a sequence of pointwise bounded and equicontinous real or complex valued functions then this sequence is uniformally bounded (without using arzela ascoli ) ...what i was thinking that K is compact so totally bounded but together with the given conditions i could do something but i got stucked so any help ?or hints how to develop those arguments ?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Pick a $\delta>0$ from equicontinuity. The collection $\{B(z,\delta)\}_{z \in X}$ is an open cover. If $z_1, \cdots, z_n$ correspond to a finite subcover, use pointwise boundedness on these fintely many points.

Comment: So it will be |fn(x)| = |fn(x)-fn(xi)+fn(xi)| <E +C(xi) right ?

Comment: Then take a max over the finitely many $C(x_i)$.

Comment: Aaaaa great :) thank you Rick

Comment: Can we generalize it to an uncountably family of such functions ? How ?

Comment: Of course, instead of saying something like "for every $n$...", say "for every $f$..."

Comment: Yeah we have not use n except that sentence so thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Each $x \in K$ has a neighbourhood $U(x)$ such that for $y \in U(x)$ and any $n$, $|f_n(y) - f_n(x)| < 1$.  Take a finite subcover...